# Synchronization with semaphores

Tags: c, semaphore

This program operates on shared memory. It creates 4 child processes that increment the int value (initially 0) in the shared memory up to a MAXCOUNT (100k here).

When a child sees that the int value in the shared memory is equal to MAXCOUNT, it stops incrementing it. Sometimes it works and the int value in the shared memory is exactly MAXCOUNT, sometimes it is 1 or 2 above.

My last output was:

```
Process 3 incremented value by 24138.
Process 2 incremented value by 26471.
Process 1 incremented value by 23247.
Process 0 incremented value by 26145.
Shared Memory = 100001, MAXCOUNT = 100000
```

Which is 1 above the limit.
How is this possible and how can one solve that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAXCOUNT 100000
#define NUM_CHILDREN 4
#define SHMSEGSIZE sizeof(int)

int main(){
    int i, shmID, *shared_mem, count = 0;
    int pid[NUM_CHILDREN];
    shmID  = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHMSEGSIZE*2, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    shared_mem  = (int *)shmat(shmID, 0, 0);
    *shared_mem = 0;

    sem_t *mysem = (sem_t*)(shared_mem+1);
    sem_init(mysem, 1, 1);

    for (i=0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();

        if (pid[i] == -1) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }
        if (pid[i] == 0) {

            /* problem here */
            while (*shared_mem < MAXCOUNT) {
                sem_wait(mysem);
                *shared_mem += 1;
                sem_post(mysem);
                count++;
            }   
            /* problem here */

            printf("Process %i incremented value by %i.\n", i, count);
            shmdt(shared_mem);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
        waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0);
    }
    printf("Shared Memory = %i, MAXCOUNT = %i\n", *shared_mem, MAXCOUNT);
    shmdt(shared_mem);
    shmctl(shmID, IPC_RMID, 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT:

I changed the problem section to:

```
while (1) {
    sem_wait(mysem);
    if(*shared_mem < MAXCOUNT){
        *shared_mem += 1;
    }else{
        break;
    }
    sem_post(mysem);
    count++;
}
```

But now I think I produced a deadlock, because my output is this:

```
Process 2 incremented value by 23775.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are checking `*shared_mem < MAXCOUNT` **outside the locked section**.

```
while (*shared_mem < MAXCOUNT) {
    /* XXX: other threads have a chance to change shared_mem before you lock. */
    sem_wait(mysem);
    *shared_mem += 1;
    sem_post(mysem);
    count++;
}
```

You should restructure your code such that you include the check inside the critical section.

---

#### Edit

In light of comment and edited question: your new code breaks without unlocking the semaphore. The other threads remain stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
the posted code has the following loop,
which is checking the value of shared_mem, Then waiting
During that wait, another child process could/will increment shared_mem
Then this child increments shared_mem
the result is over counting

while (*shared_mem < MAXCOUNT)
{
    sem_wait(mysem);
    *shared_mem += 1;
    sem_post(mysem);
    count++;
}

suggest:

do
{
    sem_wait(mysem);
    if( *shared_mem < MAXCOUNT )
    {
        *shared_mem++;
    }
    sem_post(mysem);
    count++;
}  while( *shared_mem <MAX_COUNT );
```

Comment: Not sure why this is the answer?!?

Comment: Missclick. The solution is my edit but with an unlock in the if-segment before the break.